# std::optional implemented as union vs char[]/aligned_storage

Tags: c++, c++17, unions, placement-new, stdoptional

While reading through GCC's implementation of `std::optional` I noticed something interesting. I know `boost::optional` is implemented as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class optional {
    // ...
private:
    bool has_value_;
    aligned_storage<T, /* ... */> storage_;
}
```

But then both *libstdc++* and *libc++* (and *Abseil*) implement their `optional` types like this:

```
template <typename T>
class optional {
    // ...
private:
    struct empty_byte {};
    union {
        empty_byte empty_;
        T value_;
    };
    bool has_value_;
}
```

They look to me as they are functionally identical, but are there any advantages of using one over the other? (Except for the obvious lack of placement new in the latter which is really nice.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> They look to me as they are functionally identical, but are there any advantages of using one over the other? (Except for the obvious lack placement new in the latter which is really nice.)

It's not just "really nice" - it's critical for a really important bit of functionality, namely:

```
constexpr std::optional<int> o(42);
```

There are several things you *cannot* do in a constant expression, and those include `new` and `reinterpret_cast`. If you implemented `optional` with `aligned_storage`, you would need to use the `new` to create the object and `reinterpret_cast` to get it back out, which would prevent `optional` from being `constexpr` friendly.

With the `union` implementation, you don't have this problem, so you can use `optional` in `constexpr` programming (even before the [fix for trivial copyability](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0602r3.html) that [Nicol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52338325/2069064) is talking about, [`optional`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/optional) was already required to be usable as `constexpr`).

Answer (score 14):

`std::optional` *cannot* be implemented as aligned storage, due to a post-C++17 defect fix. Specifically, `std::optional<T>` is required to be trivially copyable if `T` is trivially copyable. A `union{empty; T t};` will satisfy this requirement

Internal storage and placement-`new`/`delete` usage cannot. Doing a byte copy from a TriviallyCopyable object to storage that does not yet contain an object is not sufficient in the C++ memory model to actually create that object. By contrast, the compiler-generated copy of an engaged `union` over TriviallyCopyable types will be trivial and will work to create the destination object.

So `std::optional` *must* be implemented this way.

Comment: Why does a byte copy of a TriviallyCopyable object to uninitialized storage not create that object? It sounds to me like it should for most primitive types, can you give an example for why not?

Comment: @RonMordechai: Because [intro.object]/1 says so. Or rather, it lists the syntactic constructs that create objects, and "copying memory" isn't among them. Therefore, it cannot create objects. Values in memory do not give rise to objects on their own. This is a common case of UB that "works".

Comment: Why empty field is required? Will it work simply with ```union { T t; };```?

Comment: @random: Because `T` may not be default constructible. Or assignable. When the `optional` doesn't have a `T`, it has to be done in a way that it doesn't have a `T`. And if you have a union with a single element, it always stores an element of that type.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you mean that if union has single member, it will be constructed automatically? I've just experimented in Visual Studio, and constructor is not called. So it looks like union stores no object by default.